# UIStepper disclosure indicator

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uistepper

Steppers overlap with the disclosure indicator if you try to add them to a UICollectionViewListCell using: cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator(), .customView(configuration: .init(customView: UIStepper(), placement: .trailing()))].

What's the correct way to add a stepper to the accessories of a cell then?

Example that you can run:

```
class GridViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Section {
        case main
    }

    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>! = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "VC"
        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension GridViewController {
    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
    }
}

extension GridViewController {
    private func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    private func configureDataSource() {
        
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Int> { (cell, indexPath, identifier) in
            cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator(), .customView(configuration: .init(customView: UIStepper(), placement: .trailing()))]
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Int>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }

        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Int>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems([1])
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator(), .customView(configuration: .init(customView: UIStepper(), placement: .trailing(), reservedLayoutWidth: .actual))]
```